# Ruby on Rails ufinished

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bi0Y.png)
I have been trying execute  the command --> rails new weblog in Terminal from Linux Mint after install Ruby however the application cannot be complete with the same error message, below:

Comment: Please post the error here.

Comment: Can you post the command you run? And the output of command `gem list` will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Either bundle install or rake exec bundle install

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand from the logs referenced in the question is that you are not executing `bundle install` command inside the project directory i.e. **weblog**. So first `cd` to **weblog**.

```
cd weblog
bundle install
```

I hope this helps!.